# How to propose a new trove classifier on PyPI

Tags: python, catalog, pypi

We manage a C++/Python framework called Bob (http://idiap.github.io/bob/). We have arranged so that you can easily install Bob on a selected set of platforms and then use PyPI to download and install applications using our library.

We already have around [50-70 packages now on PyPI](https://github.com/idiap/bob/wiki/Satellite-Packages). It is getting difficult to track the growth. One possibility somebody suggested was the use of PyPI [trove classifiers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=list_classifiers) to be able to tag packages that would work with our framework.

I've searched around the net, but did not find a clear set of guidelines or rules on how/when to apply for a new trove classifier to be added to PyPI. Are there any? How to apply?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about publishing software, and not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that requests like this are usually submitted through the bugtracker (on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/pypi/support-requests/search/?q=trove) or [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/issues?q=trove)).

You should try on one of them, SF seems to be more active.

Comment: As of 2015, the repo at bitbucket seems much more active.

Comment: This seems to be the correct link nowadays: https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/new?title=Request+trove+classifier&template=new-trove-classifier.md

Answer (score 2):

The pypi [help docs](https://pypi.org/help) on [adding a trove classifier](https://pypi.org/help/#new-classifier) send you to https://github.com/pypa/trove-classifiers/ where you can create issues to request new classifiers or add them via PR.